# Angular ux-grid issues with infinite scroller. how to set limit programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am using the angular ux grid [here](https://github.com/webux/ux-angularjs-datagrid)  with the infinite scroller addon.
There is so little documentation on it, but does anyone know how to programmatically set the record 'limit' so that the 'loading' template row disappears if the number of records does not meet the 'limit' value?

The only example from the docs is given here. The problem is that I don't know what my limit will be when I define the grid.

```
<div data-ux-datagrid="items" class="datagrid" data-options="{infiniteScroll: {limit:200}}" data-addons="iScrollAddon, infiniteScroll, gridLogger">
    <script type="template/html" data-template-name="default" data-template-item="item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text">{{item.id}} {{$id}} {{counter}}</div>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="template/html" data-template-name="loadingRow" data-template-item="item">
        <div class="row loadingRow"></div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `{infiniteScroll: {limit:{{myoption.mylimit}}}}` or bind an object `data-options="myOption"` ? Can you prepare a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

I actually posted the question to Wes Jones at Github and he responded.

...to do it from a controller it would be like this.

```
$scope.items = [...];

var grid = $scope.$$childHead.datagrid; (if it is the first element in that scope).

grid.options.infiniteScroll.limit = 10;
```

worked great.

Thanks Wes!